# What is the purpose of the command squads?

Tags: close-combat-last-stand-arnhem

In [Close Combat: Last Stand: Arnhem](http://www.matrixgames.com/products/386/details/Close.Combat.-.Last.Stand.Arnhem) (a Close Combat 2 remake) both sides typically have between 1 and 3 squads which are 'command' squads, which are typically infantry armed with semiautomatic rifles or submachine guns.  Do these teams serve some additional strategic or tactical purpose, or are they simply mid-range high-morale combat units?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command squads have a command radius.  Other squads inside that command radius will have their morale and skills boosted.